# Избежать переход иконки и кнопок управления окном из QMdiSubWindow в QMenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qmdiarea, qmdisubwindow

Я не уверен, что это ожидаемый результат или я сделал ошибку в своем коде. 
Следующий код дает мне результат, который не кажется интуитивно понятным. Кнопки свертывания/разворачивания/закрытия для `QMdiSubWindows` в конечном итоге сливаются с областью строки меню.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow, QPlainTextEdit

class TestApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.mdiArea = QMdiArea()
        self.mdiArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdiArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test App')
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.showMaximized()
        subWin = QMdiSubWindow()
        child = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        subWin.setWidget(child)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWin)
        subWin.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

        subWin2 = QMdiSubWindow()
        child2 = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        subWin2.setWidget(child2)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWin2)
        subWin2.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    testApp = TestApp()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат, которое меня не устраивает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу получить такое поведение при нажатие на кнопку 'Развернуть'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так. Подскажите правильный подход.

Comment: Под Ubuntu так и должно быть

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо учту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, \
    QMdiSubWindow, QPlainTextEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class TestApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()                       # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)            # +++
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        # +++
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)           # +++
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)                            # +++
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.menubar)                  # +++
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mdiArea)                  # +++
        

    def initUI(self):
        self.mdiArea = QMdiArea()   
        self.mdiArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdiArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
#        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test App')
        
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')
        
#        self.showMaximized()
        subWin = QMdiSubWindow()
        child = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        subWin.setWidget(child)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWin)
        subWin.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

        subWin2 = QMdiSubWindow()
        child2 = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        subWin2.setWidget(child2)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWin2)
        subWin2.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    testApp = TestApp()
    testApp.show()
#    testApp.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Низкий поклон. С работало. Проблема была в layout. Без вашей помощи признаюсь, долго бы искал. Еще раз спасибо!